# mcp puppet runonce not executing manifests

Tags: puppet, puppetmaster, mcollective

I am using `mcollective` with `puppet` . The setup is successful . But when I apply manifests , the manifests is not getting executed . My manifests is as follows:

```
    node default{
```

}

```
node 'Node-009.wiley.com'{
```

file { "/tmp/helloworld.txt":
     ensure => file,
     owner  => "root",
     group  => "root",
     mode   => 0644,
     content => "Hello, World",
     }

```
$# mco puppet runonce

* [ ============================================================> ] 4 / 4

Finished processing 4 / 4 hosts in 237.47 ms
```

mco ping is also working fine

```
  # mco ping
 Node-003.wiley.com                   time=109.87 ms
 Node-002.wiley.com                   time=112.70 ms
 Node-010.wiley.com                   time=115.81 ms
 Node-009.wiley.com                   time=118.32 ms


  ---- ping statistics ----
  4 replies max: 118.32 min: 109.87 avg: 114.18
```

Please suggest clues what I am missing because of which the manifests are not getting applied.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help you.

Run this command:

`mco puppet runonce -S Node-009.wiley.com`

Comment: This needs a lot more details to be a useful answer.